# Restore mongo dump in docker container returns "Failed: EOF"

Tags: mongodb

When trying to restore a mongo dump created with:

```
docker exec mongo sh -c "mongodump --db=prod --archive --gzip" > file.dump.gz
```

using the command line:

```
docker exec mongo sh -c "mongorestore --archive --gzip --db=prod --drop" < file.dump.gz
```

I get the following output:

```
2021-01-20T18:39:33.129+0000    Failed: EOF
2021-01-20T18:39:33.129+0000    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that mongorestore can't access correctly stdin **if you don't tell docker to allocate stdin with the -i flag**, so the command should look like this:

```
docker exec -i mongo sh -c "mongorestore --archive --gzip --db=prod --drop" < file.dump.gz
```

Comment: It worked for me! file.dump.gz had to be on my computer, not in the Docker container